# How to start service API 28+

Tags: android

I have a problem. How can I start a service that won't kill when I close the app?
I'm trying to make a notification service and I need to it be live in background and won't end until I want. Sorry for my bad English.I'm using android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it guys. Thanks however.

Main Activity.java

```
getApplicationContext().startForegroundService(new Intent(dis, foregroundService.class));
```

foregroundService.java

```
 public class foregroundService extends Service {
    private Handler handler = new Handler();
    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return null;
        
    }
    private void start (){
        handler.postDelayed(runnable, 6000);
    }
    private Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Toast.makeText(foregroundService.this, "Refresh", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                start();
        }
    };

    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // dont show the notification//
        startForeground(1,new Notification.Builder(this).build());
        Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        start();

    }
}
```